# opencv matrix multi channel access and fill

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, channel

I have a matrix  with 3 channels, and I have a problem to access and change the value of the elements. I have this code:

```
Mat m(4,4, CV_8UC3);   
Vec3b a;
a[0] = 255;
a[1] = 0;
a[2] = 0;
m.at<Vec3b>(0,0) = a;
```

when I print the matrix m, I have this :

```
[255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

which is good, but the image that I get when I store the matrix with `imwrite` is this one:

[image]

and I don't understand why it's blue and why I have a square 2x2 blue, I should have had only the first pixel red no?

Have I done a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, pixels next to the high-intensity pixel take non-zero values after JPG-compression because JPEG is a lossy algorithm. In fact, JPEG-compression discards information precisely in image regions with strong gradient.

As for your second question: your pixels are blue because of an Opencv quirk: color channels are not stored in R, G, B order, but in B, G, R order:

> For color images, the channel ordering is normally Blue, Green, Red

Source: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=green

(this is one of those things that make life miserable for the Opencv programmer)

Comment: This is not OpenCV quirk but Windows quirk. If you write your 3-channel image buffer to disk as is (as bmp or ppm) and open it in some picture viewer you will see that it is treated as BGR image not RGB image. For OpenCV to have the image in RGB format means swapping image pixels for each imread and imwrite. This is just waste time in many cases.

Comment: Ok, so it's a BMP and PPM quirk that became an Opencv quirk :) Do you happen to know if pixels are swapped when saving/reading JPG or PNG?

Comment: BMP and PPM are just an examples of the formats that store the image buffer as is without compression of any kind. If you allocated 1 megabyte of memory for your image and store it on your hard disk it will take 1 mega-byte on your hard disk. This is not the case for PNG or JPEG. Those images will be smaller which means that they were compressed (loss-less compression for PNG and lossy compression for JPG). Thus the question about swapping is meaningless because those formats are not storing values of pixels but data from which those values can be recovered.

Answer (score 3):

> **I don't understand why it's blue ... not red?**

In OpenCV, the image format is set by the flag when you create the image e.g. `CV_8UC3` means 8bit pixels, unsigned, 3 color channels. In a color image the pixel order is `BGR`, data is stored in row order. Similarly, `BGRA` for `CV_8UC4`. So the value you set is blue instead of red, that's why you got blue.

> **I should have had only the first pixel ...?**

The reason is that, for compressed image types e.g. `JPG`, they can not guarantee to keep the content precisely. Try to `imwrite()` to a un-compressed e.g. `BMP` image (typically). You will get the image like:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! It works! But I don't understand why? Jpg is bad?

Comment: `JPG` is a compressed image type, which will not always keep the content precisely.